# C++ pointer memory leak

Tags: c++, memory

I just started learning c++ and i am facing a `free(): invalid pointer: error. Under gdb debug, the error show

> [Thread 0xb7caab40 (LWP 4405) exited]
>
> *** Error in `/home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2': free(): invalid pointer: 0xb74a9b40 ***
>
> Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted. 0xb7fdd424 in
>   __kernel_vsyscall ()

in valgrid

> ==4487== 800 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 1 of 1
>
> ==4487==    at 0x402ADFC: operator new[](unsigned int) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x80560B9: Assignm3::Maze::InitMazeArray() (in /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x805516B: Assignm3::Maze::LoadMaze(std::string) (in /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804A3C4: solveMaze(void*) (in /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x4052F6F: start_thread (pthread_create.c:312)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x42A170D: clone (clone.S:129)
>
> ==4487==
>
> ==4487== LEAK SUMMARY:
>
> ==4487==    definitely lost: 800 bytes in 1 blocks
>
> ==4487==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==4487==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==4487==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==4487==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
>
> ==4487==
>
> ==4487== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
>
> ==4487==
>
> ==4487== 1 errors in context 1 of 2:
>
> ==4487== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
>
> ==4487==    at 0x402B838: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804EF2E: __gnu_cxx::new_allocator::deallocate(Point*, unsigned int) (in /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804E9F6: std::_Vector_base 
>   ::_M_deallocate(Point*, unsigned int) (in
>   /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804E883: std::_Vector_base >::~_Vector_base() (in
>   /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804E2F6: std::vector >::~vector() (in /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x804E25B: Assignm3::PathFinderResource::~PathFinderResource() (in
>   /home/a/Desktop/PathFinder2)
>   ==4487==    by 0x41E83D0: __run_exit_handlers (exit.c:82)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x41E842C: exit (exit.c:104)
>
> ==4487==    by 0x41CEA8A: (below main) (libc-start.c:321)
>
> ==4487==  Address 0x5768b40 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
>
> ==4487==
>
> ==4487== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)

Here's my coding

```
static void *solveMaze(void *vptr_args)
{
  Point point1, point2, point3;
  int nxtPx, nxtPy;
  mazeObj->LoadMaze();
  point1 = mazeObj->getStartLocation();
  point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
  VectorOfPointStructType Path, vecMain;
  Path.push_back(point1);
  vecMain.push_back(point1);
  point2 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
  nxtPx = point1.getX();
  nxtPy = point1.getY();

  sleep(3);
  while (true)
  {
      string thread1, thread2;
      thread1 = THREAD_NAMES[line1];
      thread2 = THREAD_NAMES[line2];
      cout << "Thread " << THREAD_NAMES[line1] << " is running" << endl;
      cout << "Thread " << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " is running" << endl;
  for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
  {
     if (thread1 != THREAD_NAMES[line1] && thread2 != THREAD_NAMES[line2])
     {
       cout << "Thread " << THREAD_NAMES[line1] << " is running" << endl;
       cout << "Thread " << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " is running" << endl;
      }

  if (x == 0)
  {
    nxtPx++;
    point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy);
    if ((mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) || mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, ob))
    {
      Path.push_back(point3);
      vecMain.push_back(point3);
      ob.push_back(point3);
      if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToBarrier(pthread_self(), Path))
        {
          sleep(1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      else if (mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToDangerArea(pthread_self(), Path))
        {

          if (thread1 == THREAD_NAMES[line1])
          {

            diemsg1();

          }
          else if (thread2 == THREAD_NAMES[line2])
          {

            diemsg2();

          }

          create();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      nxtPx--;
      Path.pop_back();
    }
    else if ((!mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) && !mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3,
      vecMain))
    {
      point1 = point3;
      Path.push_back(point1);
      vecMain.push_back(point1);
      point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
      x =  - 1;
      if (point1.isConnected(point2) || reachEnd)
      {
        reachEnd = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      nxtPx--;
    }

  }
  else if (x == 1)
  {
    nxtPy++;
    point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy);
    if ((mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) || mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, ob))
    {

      Path.push_back(point3);
      vecMain.push_back(point3);
      ob.push_back(point3);

      if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToBarrier(pthread_self(), Path))
        {
          sleep(1);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      else if (mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToDangerArea(pthread_self(), Path))
        {

          if (thread1 == THREAD_NAMES[line1])
          {

            diemsg1();

          }
          else if (thread2 == THREAD_NAMES[line2])
          {

            diemsg2();

          }

          create();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      nxtPy--;
      Path.pop_back();
    }
    else if ((!mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) && !mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3,
      vecMain))
    {
      point1 = point3;
      Path.push_back(point1);
      vecMain.push_back(point1);
      point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
      x =  - 1;
      if (point1.isConnected(point2) || reachEnd)
      {
        reachEnd = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      nxtPy--;
    }
  }
  else if (x == 2)
  {
    nxtPx--;
    point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy);
    if ((mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) || mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, ob))
    {

      Path.push_back(point3);
      vecMain.push_back(point3);
      ob.push_back(point3);
      if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToBarrier(pthread_self(), Path))
        {
          sleep(2);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      else if (mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);
        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToDangerArea(pthread_self(), Path))
        {

          if (thread1 == THREAD_NAMES[line1])
          {

            diemsg1();

          }
          else if (thread2 == THREAD_NAMES[line2])
          {

            diemsg2();

          }

          create();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      nxtPx++;
      Path.pop_back();
    }
    else if ((!mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) && !mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3,
      vecMain))
    {
      point1 = point3;
      Path.push_back(point1);
      vecMain.push_back(point1);
      point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
      x =  - 1;
      if (point1.isConnected(point2) || reachEnd)
      {
        reachEnd = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      nxtPx++;
    }
  }
  else if (x == 3)
  {
    nxtPy--;
    point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy);
    if ((mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) || mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, ob))
    {

      Path.push_back(point3);
      vecMain.push_back(point3);
      ob.push_back(point3);

      if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToBarrier(pthread_self(), Path))
        {
          sleep(2);
        }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      else if (mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3))
      {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);


        if (submitMazeSolnObj->submitPathToDangerArea(pthread_self(), Path))
        {

          if (thread1 == THREAD_NAMES[line1])
          {

            diemsg1();

          }
          else if (thread2 == THREAD_NAMES[line2])
          {

            diemsg2();

          }

          create();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
      }
      nxtPy++;
      Path.pop_back();
    }
    else if ((!mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3) && !mazeObj->IsThereDanger(point3)) && !pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3,
      vecMain))
    {
      point1 = point3;
      Path.push_back(point1);
      vecMain.push_back(point1);
      point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
      x =  - 1;
      if (point1.isConnected(point2) || reachEnd)
      {
        reachEnd = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    else
    {
      nxtPy++;
    }
  }
  else if (x == 4)
  {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex1);

    for (;;)
    {

      point1 = Path[Path.size() - 2];
      nxtPx = point1.getX();
      nxtPy = point1.getY();
      point3 = Point(nxtPx - 1, nxtPy);

      if (!pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, vecMain))
      {
        x = 0;
        Path.pop_back();

        if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
        {
          point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        break;
      }
      point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy + 1);

      if (!pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, vecMain))
      {
        x =  - 1;
        Path.pop_back();

        if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
        {
          point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        break;
      }
      point3 = Point(nxtPx + 1, nxtPy);

      if (!pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, vecMain))
      {
        x = 2;
        Path.pop_back();

        if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
        {
          point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        break;
      }

      point3 = Point(nxtPx, nxtPy - 1);

      if (!pathObj->isLocationInPath(point3, vecMain))
      {
        x = 1;
        Path.pop_back();

        if (mazeObj->IsThereBarrier(point3))
        {
          point3 = mazeObj->getEndLocation();
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
        break;
      }
      Path.pop_back();
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex1);
    int deX = point1.getX();
    int deY = point1.getY();

    if (thread1 == THREAD_NAMES[line1])
    {

      time(&end);
      cout << "Thread: " << THREAD_NAMES[line1] << " found the dead end at " << "[ " << deX << " , " << deY << " ]" << endl;
      cout << "Time Elapsed: " << difftime(end, start) << " seconds" << endl;

    }
    else if (thread2 == THREAD_NAMES[line2])
    {


      time(&end);
      cout << "Thread: " << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " found the dead end at " << "[ " << deX << " , " << deY << " ]" << endl;
      cout << "Time Elapsed: " << difftime(end, start) << " seconds" << endl;
    }
  }
  else
  {}
}
 {
 break;
 }
}
 Path.push_back(point2);
 if (!submitPath)
 {
  submitMazeSolnObj->submitSolutionPath(pthread_self(), Path);
  submitPath = true;
 }
 return NULL;
}
```

> Blockquote

```
int main() 
{   
    AllocateProgramsVariableMemory();
    mazeObj->LoadMaze();
    string thread_Msg = "";
    string * thread_message = &thread_Msg;

    if (pthread_create(&myPFR.activeThreadArray[line1], NULL, solveMaze, thread_message) != 0) 
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << THREAD_NAMES[line1] << " has been created" << endl;
    }
 //---------------causing error--------------------------------------------
    if (pthread_create(&myPFR.activeThreadArray[line2], NULL, solveMaze, thread_message) != 0) 
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " has been created" << endl;
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
    if (pthread_join(myPFR.activeThreadArray[line1], NULL) != 0) 
    {   
        return EXIT_FAILURE;       
    }

    if (pthread_join(myPFR.activeThreadArray[line2], NULL) != 0) 
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    DeallocateProgramsVariableMemory();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

> Blockquote

```
typedef std::vector<Point> VectorOfPointStructType;

namespace myx
static Maze * mazeObj;
static Path * pathObj;
static SubmitMazeSoln * submitMazeSolnObj;

static void AllocateProgramsVariableMemory (void)
{
    mazeObj             = new Maze ();
    pathObj             = new Path ();
    submitMazeSolnObj   = new SubmitMazeSoln ();

    logFileStream.open (DefaultLogFilename.c_str(), std::fstream::out);

}

static void DeallocateProgramsVariableMemory (void)
{
    delete mazeObj;
    delete pathObj;
    delete submitMazeSolnObj;

    logFileStream.close ();
    pthread_mutex_destroy ( &thread_mutex );
    pthread_cond_destroy  ( &thread_condition );

}

struct PathFinderResource
{
    pthread_t                       activeThreadArray       [MAX_NO_OF_THREADS];
    PathFinderParameterInfo *       activeThreadParamArray  [MAX_NO_OF_THREADS];

    VectorOfPointStructType         solutionPath;
    VectorOfPointStructType         discoveredDangerAreas;
    int                             usedThreadNameIndex;
    int                             noOfDeadEndPathsFound;
    int                             noOfBarriersDiscovered;
    int                             noOfDangerAreaDiscovered;

    PathFinderResource (void)
    {
        usedThreadNameIndex         = 0;
        noOfDeadEndPathsFound       = 0;
        noOfBarriersDiscovered      = 0;
        noOfDangerAreaDiscovered    = 0;
        solutionPath                = VectorOfPointStructType ();
        discoveredDangerAreas       = VectorOfPointStructType ();
    }

    ~PathFinderResource (void)
    {
        solutionPath.clear ();
        discoveredDangerAreas.clear ();
    }
};
```

Comment: `I just started learning c++` So why are you jumping into using threads if you're just learning C++?  One way to not have this error is to use smart pointers, not raw pointers.

Comment: Please reduce the code so we can more easily digest the problem. Most likely you're deleting a pointer that's already been deleted or has not been allocated or has been accessed outside of the size you allocated

Comment: PaulMcKenzie - my assignment requires threading.                               cppguy- how do i know if im deleting a pointer that is already deleted? i tried to comment my main function to not free the memory and the error still remain. Thanks

Comment: @A.allen My point is that you can't write a program that uses threads if you can't write the same program without threads, or worse, not know how to properly use / debug in the language you're creating the threads with.  Drop the raw pointer usage and use `unique_ptr` or other smart pointer, and your problem(s) may disappear.

Comment: @A.allen `how do i know if im deleting a pointer that is already deleted?`  You're using threads, and once you do that, you must be aware of all the issues that are associated with them, for example data races.  It is *not* a trivial topic, which is why you should write the single thread version of your program first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Please don't use code style for emphasis. I personally prefer _"plain citing"_ <<<<, but code style should be for code. Sorry about nitpicking.

Comment: The trace points to `mazeObj->LoadMaze();` which both threads call very early. There we see names like `InitMazeArray` and `operator new[]`. My gut feeling says that both threads allocate the same array, and then delete it twice. That would also explain the 800 byte memory leak.

Comment: The complaint is from `free()`, presumably called by the `std::vector` destructor, called by the `PathFinderResource::~PathFinderResource()` destructor.  But we see no source code for that class.  I think the cause lies there.

Answer (score 1):

```
static void *solveMaze(void *vptr_args)
{
  //...
  mazeObj->LoadMaze();
  //...
}

int main()
{
  static Maze * mazeObj;
  static Path * pathObj;
  static SubmitMazeSoln * submitMazeSolnObj;
  //...
}
```

With reference to the code here above... There is no way that mazeObj in main will have scope in solveMaze. Where does solveMaze get its mazeObj. Either it's not the same mazeObj, or this is not the real code.

Regards,

Werner

Comment: You are right.  Scope is one of a number of problems to fix.  While I upvoted your answer, and it's a very good point, I think this particular problem is not what leads to a `free()` of an invalid pointer.

Comment: @donjuedo. Agreed, it may be unrelated, but the OP seems to have no clue wrt the scope, and he hasn't posted all the code, and the code in main doesn't do what he thinks, which I at least wanted to highlight (hard to show this in comment)

Comment: @Werner Erasmus It's has nothing to do with the  `mazeObj->LoadMaze();`.  The error still occur even after `mazeObj->LoadMaze();` to be at main.                                                                                                                                                    @donjuedo  my 'PathFinderResource::~PathFinderResource() destructor' does not have `free` function.

Comment: I suspect the error lies here `if (pthread_create(&myPFR.activeThreadArray[line2], NULL, solveMaze, thread_message) != 0) 
    {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    else 
    {
        cout << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " has been created" << endl;
    }`

Comment: @A.allen, the point is that all code is not posted, and having mazeobj static in main hardly makes sense. Also, he doesn't join in main on threads... Everything is wrong with the structure of his program.

Comment: @A.allen Right, `PathFinderResource::~PathFinderResource()` does not have a `free()` function.  It leads to that call, though, as shown by the call stack you posted.  `PathFinderResource` appears to have a data member of type `std::vector` and something is wrong with its destruction.

Comment: @ donjuedo i have update the code, i notice the error is caused by this function under main function `if (pthread_create(&myPFR.activeThreadArray[line2], NULL, solveMaze, thread_message) != 0) 
    {
      return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } 
    else 
   {
       cout << THREAD_NAMES[line2] << " has been created" << endl;
   }`